# Bind onclick to enter key

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2010

I have a small search box in a content editor web part on my SharePoint site. The user inputs some text into a text box and then has to CLICK an image which serves as the submit button (clicking the image loads the javascript function onclick.)

This is pretty terrible as you cannot press enter to search.

Is there any way to set up the image or onClick() so that it detects Enter being pressed, like a normal submit button?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Wrap it in a `<form>` and use its onsubmit event instead

Comment: Yes, I'm giving it a try, but I don't think it's going to work due to the nature of it (it's not my code.. :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `onclick()` no, it is not, but you can use `onkeyup()`:

```
yourTextField.onkeyup=function(){
    if(event.keyCode==13){
        //enter pressed!
    }
}
```

Comment: Have just realised - it works for IE and Chrome, but not Firefox. Any idea why this is @nicael?

Comment: Firebug says: ReferenceError: event is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

if(event.keyCode==13)

Comment: no joy :( apparently firefox handles events differently... https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/942488

Comment: @brainZap what if you try to use `yourTextField.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {if(evt.keyCode==13){/*enter pressed!*/}}, false);`?

Comment: That method didn't work in Firefox or IE but worked in Chrome. To be honest, virtually nobody who uses the page will be using Firefox anyway, so i'll go with the first method